How powerful is Quantum Turing machine with an oracle access to NP?
I would like to know the upper bound on the class of problem efficiently solved by a BQP (machine) with access to:
(i) a single (oracular) call to NP machine (or, $BQP^{NP[1]}$)
(ii) poly-logarithmic number of call to NP machine (or, $BQP^{NP[log(n)]}$)
(ii) polynomially many call to NP machine (or, $BQP^{NP}$)
Main query: Is class QMA (Quantum Merlin Arthur) class contained in the case(iii)?

My attempt:

By definition of QCMA (Quantum-Classical Merlin Arthur) which requires classical proof from Merlin to be verified by Arthur (BQP verifier). As per my undersatnding, the classical proof can be guessed by the (all powerful) Merlin (who is assumed to have an access to NP oracle too).

Claim I: Thus I infer $QCMA\subseteq BQP^{NP}$

By definition of QMA (Quantum Merlin Arthur) which requires quantum proof from Merlin to be verified by Arthur (BQP verifier).
As per my undersatnding, the quantum proof is guessed by the Merlin (who is assumed to have an access to quantum non-deterministic machine (say, QNDTM).

Query-I:  Is power of QNDTM captured by (a) $BQP^{NP}$ or is it (b) $NP^{BQP}$?
If (a) is the case then $QMA\subseteq BQP^{BQP^{NP}} = BQP^{NP}$. (due to self low property of BQP class).

The classical witness that Merlin guesses using ^{} has to be a classical witness for an NP problem, not a classical witness for a QCMA problem. So your argument for Claim 1 doesn't seem to work; it's not clear that QCMA ⊆ BQP^{NP}.

@Peter, point taken. I see the flaw in my argument.
// side comment: (I) I am now looking for how $QCMA$ and $BQP^{NP}$ behave in a relativized world.

(continue...) (II) I am aware of one (weak!) supporting argument for posing the conjecture $QCMA\subseteq BQP^{NP}$. This is due to quantum-classical PCP conjecture. If it holds then $QCMA\subseteq BQP^{NP[1]}$!!! [ ref: Theorem 1.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.11578 along with their conjecture about QC-PCP.
